# error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)

Tags: apt, dpkg, dependencies

could someone help me please?
I am trying to free some space on the Boot, but it gives me that:

> :~$ sudo apt autoremove
> ...
> E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

**UPDATE:**

I tried to delete old kernels following the steps from this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89710/how-do-i-free-up-more-space-in-boot). It gives me the same answer

**SIMULATION**

```
:~$ sudo dpkg --simulate -P $(dpkg -l 'linux-*' | sed '/^ii/!d;/'"$(uname -r | sed "s/\(.*\)-\([^0-9]\+\)/\1/")"'/d;s/^[^ ]* [^ ]* \([^ ]*\).*/\1/;/[0-9]/!d')  
[sudo] password for lisa: 
(Reading database ... 441732 files and directories currently installed.)
Would remove or purge linux-generic-hwe-20.04 (5.15.0.91.88) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of linux-headers-5.15.0-92-generic:
 linux-headers-generic depends on linux-headers-5.15.0-92-generic.

dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-5.15.0-92-generic (--purge):
 dependency problems - not removing
Would remove or purge linux-headers-6.2.0-33-generic (6.2.0-33.33~22.04.1) ...
Would remove or purge linux-headers-6.2.0-39-generic (6.2.0-39.40~22.04.1) ...
Would remove or purge linux-headers-6.5.0-15-generic (6.5.0-15.15~22.04.1) ...
Would remove or purge linux-headers-6.5.0-21-generic (6.5.0-21.21~22.04.1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of linux-headers-generic-hwe-22.04:
 linux-generic-hwe-22.04 depends on linux-headers-generic-hwe-22.04 (= 6.5.0.25.25~22.04.12).

dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-generic-hwe-22.04 (--purge):
 dependency problems - not removing
Would remove or purge linux-hwe-6.2-headers-6.2.0-33 (6.2.0-33.33~22.04.1) ...
Would remove or purge linux-hwe-6.2-headers-6.2.0-39 (6.2.0-39.40~22.04.1) ...
Would remove or purge linux-hwe-6.5-headers-6.5.0-15 (6.5.0-15.15~22.04.1) ...
Would remove or purge linux-hwe-6.5-headers-6.5.0-21 (6.5.0-21.21~22.04.1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of linux-image-5.15.0-92-generic:
 linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-5.15.0-92-generic.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.15.0-92-generic (--purge):
 dependency problems - not removing
Would remove or purge linux-image-6.2.0-33-generic (6.2.0-33.33~22.04.1) ...
Would remove or purge linux-image-6.2.0-39-generic (6.2.0-39.40~22.04.1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of linux-libc-dev:amd64:
 libc6-dev:amd64 depends on linux-libc-dev.

dpkg: error processing package linux-libc-dev:amd64 (--purge):
 dependency problems - not removing
dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of linux-modules-5.15.0-92-generic:
 linux-image-5.15.0-92-generic depends on linux-modules-5.15.0-92-generic.

dpkg: error processing package linux-modules-5.15.0-92-generic (--purge):
 dependency problems - not removing
Would remove or purge linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-91-generic (5.15.0-91.101) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-92-generic:
 linux-image-generic depends on linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-92-generic.

dpkg: error processing package linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-92-generic (--purge):
 dependency problems - not removing
Would remove or purge linux-modules-extra-6.2.0-33-generic (6.2.0-33.33~22.04.1) ...
Would remove or purge linux-modules-extra-6.2.0-39-generic (6.2.0-39.40~22.04.1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of linux-headers-5.15.0-92:
 linux-headers-5.15.0-92-generic depends on linux-headers-5.15.0-92.

dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-5.15.0-92 (--purge):
 dependency problems - not removing
dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of linux-headers-6.5.0-25-generic:
 linux-headers-generic-hwe-22.04 depends on linux-headers-6.5.0-25-generic.

dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-6.5.0-25-generic (--purge):
 dependency problems - not removing
dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of linux-hwe-6.5-headers-6.5.0-25:
 linux-headers-6.5.0-25-generic depends on linux-hwe-6.5-headers-6.5.0-25.

dpkg: error processing package linux-hwe-6.5-headers-6.5.0-25 (--purge):
 dependency problems - not removing
Would remove or purge linux-modules-6.2.0-33-generic (6.2.0-33.33~22.04.1) ...
Would remove or purge linux-modules-6.2.0-39-generic (6.2.0-39.40~22.04.1) ...
Would remove or purge linux-modules-5.15.0-91-generic (5.15.0-91.101) ...
Would remove or purge linux-image-5.15.0-91-generic (5.15.0-91.101) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-headers-5.15.0-92-generic
 linux-headers-generic-hwe-22.04
 linux-image-5.15.0-92-generic
 linux-libc-dev:amd64
 linux-modules-5.15.0-92-generic
 linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-92-generic
 linux-headers-5.15.0-92
 linux-headers-6.5.0-25-generic
 linux-hwe-6.5-headers-6.5.0-25
```

**UPDATE**

```
:~$ uname -r
6.5.0-14-generic
```

```
:~$ dpkg -l | egrep linux-'[g|i|h|m]'
ii  binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu                     2.38-4ubuntu2.5                         amd64        GNU binary utilities, for x86-64-linux-gnu target
ii  linux-generic                                 5.15.0.92.89                            amd64        Complete Generic Linux kernel and headers
ii  linux-generic-hwe-20.04                       5.15.0.91.88                            amd64        Complete Generic Linux kernel and headers (dummy transitional package)
iU  linux-generic-hwe-22.04                       6.5.0.25.25~22.04.12                    amd64        Complete Generic Linux kernel and headers
ii  linux-headers-5.15.0-92                       5.15.0-92.102                           all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 5.15.0
ii  linux-headers-5.15.0-92-generic               5.15.0-92.102                           amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 5.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-6.2.0-33-generic                6.2.0-33.33~22.04.1                     amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 6.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-6.2.0-39-generic                6.2.0-39.40~22.04.1                     amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 6.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-6.5.0-14-generic                6.5.0-14.14~22.04.1                     amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 6.5.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-6.5.0-15-generic                6.5.0-15.15~22.04.1                     amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 6.5.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-6.5.0-21-generic                6.5.0-21.21~22.04.1                     amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 6.5.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-6.5.0-25-generic                6.5.0-25.25~22.04.1                     amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 6.5.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-generic                         5.15.0.92.89                            amd64        Generic Linux kernel headers
ii  linux-headers-generic-hwe-22.04               6.5.0.25.25~22.04.12                    amd64        Generic Linux kernel headers
ii  linux-hwe-6.2-headers-6.2.0-33                6.2.0-33.33~22.04.1                     all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 6.2.0
ii  linux-hwe-6.2-headers-6.2.0-39                6.2.0-39.40~22.04.1                     all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 6.2.0
ii  linux-hwe-6.5-headers-6.5.0-14                6.5.0-14.14~22.04.1                     all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 6.5.0
ii  linux-hwe-6.5-headers-6.5.0-15                6.5.0-15.15~22.04.1                     all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 6.5.0
ii  linux-hwe-6.5-headers-6.5.0-21                6.5.0-21.21~22.04.1                     all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 6.5.0
ii  linux-hwe-6.5-headers-6.5.0-25                6.5.0-25.25~22.04.1                     all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 6.5.0
rc  linux-image-5.11.0-22-generic                 5.11.0-22.23                            amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.11.0-25-generic                 5.11.0-25.27                            amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.11.0-31-generic                 5.11.0-31.33                            amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.11.0-34-generic                 5.11.0-34.36                            amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.11.0-36-generic                 5.11.0-36.40                            amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.11.0-37-generic                 5.11.0-37.41                            amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.11.0-38-generic                 5.11.0-38.42                            amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.11.0-40-generic                 5.11.0-40.44                            amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.11.0-41-generic                 5.11.0-41.45                            amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.11.0-44-generic                 5.11.0-44.48                            amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.11.0-49-generic                 5.11.0-49.55                            amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.13.0-40-generic                 5.13.0-40.45                            amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.15.0-78-generic                 5.15.0-78.85                            amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.15.0-79-generic                 5.15.0-79.86                            amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.15.0-82-generic                 5.15.0-82.91                            amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.15.0-84-generic                 5.15.0-84.93                            amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.15.0-86-generic                 5.15.0-86.96                            amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.15.0-88-generic                 5.15.0-88.98                            amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.15.0-89-generic                 5.15.0-89.99                            amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-5.15.0-91-generic                 5.15.0-91.101                           amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-5.15.0-92-generic                 5.15.0-92.102                           amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.8.0-25-generic                  5.8.0-25.26                             amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.8.0-41-generic                  5.8.0-41.46                             amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.8.0-43-generic                  5.8.0-43.49                             amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.8.0-44-generic                  5.8.0-44.50                             amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.8.0-45-generic                  5.8.0-45.51                             amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.8.0-48-generic                  5.8.0-48.54                             amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.8.0-49-generic                  5.8.0-49.55                             amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.8.0-50-generic                  5.8.0-50.56                             amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.8.0-53-generic                  5.8.0-53.60                             amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.8.0-55-generic                  5.8.0-55.62                             amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.8.0-59-generic                  5.8.0-59.66                             amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-6.2.0-26-generic                  6.2.0-26.26~22.04.1                     amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-6.2.0-31-generic                  6.2.0-31.31~22.04.1                     amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-6.2.0-33-generic                  6.2.0-33.33~22.04.1                     amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-6.2.0-34-generic                  6.2.0-34.34~22.04.1                     amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-6.2.0-36-generic                  6.2.0-36.37~22.04.1                     amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-6.2.0-37-generic                  6.2.0-37.38~22.04.1                     amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-6.2.0-39-generic                  6.2.0-39.40~22.04.1                     amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-6.5.0-14-generic                  6.5.0-14.14~22.04.1                     amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-generic                           5.15.0.92.89                            amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
iU  linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04                 6.5.0.25.25~22.04.12                    amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
rc  linux-modules-5.11.0-22-generic               5.11.0-22.23                            amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-5.11.0-25-generic               5.11.0-25.27                            amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-5.11.0-31-generic               5.11.0-31.33                            amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-5.11.0-34-generic               5.11.0-34.36                            amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-5.11.0-36-generic               5.11.0-36.40                            amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-5.11.0-37-generic               5.11.0-37.41                            amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-5.11.0-38-generic               5.11.0-38.42                            amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-5.11.0-40-generic               5.11.0-40.44                            amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-5.11.0-41-generic               5.11.0-41.45                            amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-5.11.0-44-generic               5.11.0-44.48                            amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-5.11.0-49-generic               5.11.0-49.55                            amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-5.13.0-40-generic               5.13.0-40.45                            amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-5.15.0-78-generic               5.15.0-78.85                            amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-5.15.0-79-generic               5.15.0-79.86                            amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-5.15.0-82-generic               5.15.0-82.91                            amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-5.15.0-84-generic               5.15.0-84.93                            amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-5.15.0-86-generic               5.15.0-86.96                            amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-5.15.0-88-generic               5.15.0-88.98                            amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-5.15.0-89-generic               5.15.0-89.99                            amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-modules-5.15.0-91-generic               5.15.0-91.101                           amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-modules-5.15.0-92-generic               5.15.0-92.102                           amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-5.8.0-25-generic                5.8.0-25.26                             amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-5.8.0-41-generic                5.8.0-41.46                             amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-5.8.0-43-generic                5.8.0-43.49                             amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-5.8.0-44-generic                5.8.0-44.50                             amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-5.8.0-45-generic                5.8.0-45.51                             amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-5.8.0-48-generic                5.8.0-48.54                             amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-5.8.0-49-generic                5.8.0-49.55                             amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-5.8.0-50-generic                5.8.0-50.56                             amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-5.8.0-53-generic                5.8.0-53.60                             amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-5.8.0-55-generic                5.8.0-55.62                             amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-5.8.0-59-generic                5.8.0-59.66                             amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-6.2.0-26-generic                6.2.0-26.26~22.04.1                     amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 6.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-6.2.0-31-generic                6.2.0-31.31~22.04.1                     amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 6.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-modules-6.2.0-33-generic                6.2.0-33.33~22.04.1                     amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 6.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-6.2.0-34-generic                6.2.0-34.34~22.04.1                     amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 6.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-6.2.0-36-generic                6.2.0-36.37~22.04.1                     amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 6.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-6.2.0-37-generic                6.2.0-37.38~22.04.1                     amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 6.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-modules-6.2.0-39-generic                6.2.0-39.40~22.04.1                     amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 6.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-modules-6.5.0-14-generic                6.5.0-14.14~22.04.1                     amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 6.5.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.11.0-22-generic         5.11.0-22.23                            amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.11.0-25-generic         5.11.0-25.27                            amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.11.0-31-generic         5.11.0-31.33                            amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.11.0-34-generic         5.11.0-34.36                            amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.11.0-36-generic         5.11.0-36.40                            amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.11.0-37-generic         5.11.0-37.41                            amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.11.0-38-generic         5.11.0-38.42                            amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.11.0-40-generic         5.11.0-40.44                            amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.11.0-41-generic         5.11.0-41.45                            amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.11.0-44-generic         5.11.0-44.48                            amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.11.0-49-generic         5.11.0-49.55                            amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-40-generic         5.13.0-40.45                            amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-78-generic         5.15.0-78.85                            amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-79-generic         5.15.0-79.86                            amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-82-generic         5.15.0-82.91                            amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-84-generic         5.15.0-84.93                            amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-86-generic         5.15.0-86.96                            amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-88-generic         5.15.0-88.98                            amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-89-generic         5.15.0-89.99                            amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-91-generic         5.15.0-91.101                           amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-92-generic         5.15.0-92.102                           amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-25-generic          5.8.0-25.26                             amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-41-generic          5.8.0-41.46                             amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-43-generic          5.8.0-43.49                             amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-44-generic          5.8.0-44.50                             amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-45-generic          5.8.0-45.51                             amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
...
```

I had to shorten up cause too long (still 3000 of those characters)

Comment: yes, so with sudo apt --fix-broken install, appears this: dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-modules-6.5.0-21-ge
neric_6.5.0-21.21~22.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './boot/System.map-6.5.0-21-generic' to '/boot/S
ystem.map-6.5.0-21-generic.dpkg-new': failed to write (No space left on device)
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

Comment: Free space in /boot filesystem.

Comment: But how? That's exactly what I was trying to do...
With sudo apt autoremove comes 'E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
'

Comment: Try this https://askubuntu.com/questions/89710/how-do-i-free-up-more-space-in-boot

Comment: It say still the same, as I try to remove old kernels, gives me the same answer:  linux-modules-extra-6.5.0-25-generic : Depends: linux-modules-6.5.0-25-generic but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Comment: This is only a simulation. `sudo dpkg --simulate -P $(dpkg -l 'linux-*' | sed '/^ii/!d;/'"$(uname -r | sed "s/\(.*\)-\([^0-9]\+\)/\1/")"'/d;s/^[^ ]* [^ ]* \([^ ]*\).*/\1/;/[0-9]/!d')` If no error accour then remove `--simulate` part from my command.

Comment: @nobody Thank you for helping out. I tried your simulation, unfortunately it does show a lot of errors. Should I copy the answer? I'm sorry I am very new in this.. I don't even know how to format my messages (thax a lot to the people who did it!!)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show `dpkg -l | egrep -v '^ii|rc'` and also the output from my simulation command. It seems there is more broken on your system.

Comment: @nobody. I updated my post showing what appears with the sentence you proposed (sorry for the format.. i don't know how to do this)

Comment: Please add `uname -r` and `dpkg -l | egrep linux-'[g|i|h|m]'`you have different kerneltrees on your system.

Comment: @nobody, done. I couldn't copy everything, it's more than 3000 characters too long...